# Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: ssh

Enabled PasswordAuthentication as yes in sshd_config file but  still getting error like Permission denied (publickey,password)

Comment: Run ssh with option `-v` to see error in detail.

Comment: Detailed error ssh: Could not resolve hostname /home/userid/virtenvNUM/ssh/id_rsa: Name or service not known

Comment: Have you a connection to the Internet?

Comment: Yes i had connection to net

Comment: The command executed was ssh -i  -v /home/user/virtenv/ssh/id_rsa -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o ForwardX11=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/home/user/virtenv/ssh/known_hosts -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=180  root@Ip

Comment: `-i` require identity_file but you set `-v` after `-i` option. change command to: `ssh -v -i /home/......`

Comment: OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Comment: debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Comment: debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *

Comment: debug1: Connecting to IP [IP] port 22.

Comment: debug1: Connection established.

Comment: debug1: identity file /home/user/virtenv/ssh/id_rsa type 1

Comment: debug1: identity file /home/user/virtenv/ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1

Comment: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0

Comment: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3

Comment: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1

Comment: debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000

Comment: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

Comment: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received

Comment: debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none

Comment: debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT

Comment: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY

Comment: debug1: Server host key: RSA some key

Comment: debug1: Host 'IP' is known and matches the RSA host key.

Comment: debug1: Found key in /home/user/virtenv/ssh/known_hosts:2

Comment: debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct

Comment: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent

Comment: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS

Comment: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received

Comment: debug1: Roaming not allowed by server

Comment: debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent

Comment: debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

Comment: debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

Comment: debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

Comment: debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/virtenv/ssh/id_rsa

Comment: debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

Comment: debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

Comment: Permission denied (publickey,password).

Comment: Please don't post multiline command output as comments: instead, [edit] your question with the requested information

Answer (score 4):

Permission of `~/.ssh` folder must be 700, `~/.ssh/id_rsa` : 600, `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` : 644

These permissions must be set on your pc and the host that connect to.

Comment: Permission of ~/.ssh was 751 ,~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub : 644,~/.ssh/id_rsa : 600,

Comment: excuse me all permission of `~/.ssh` folder and files must set to 700(folders) and 600(files).

Comment: permission of ~/.ssh folder is set to 700 and all the file permissions are set to  600 .But still the same eror  "Permission denied (publickey,password).^M"

Comment: It worked fine for me with the below permissions:

Comment: Local Host : ssh 700, files with 600

Comment: Remote: ssh 700, files with 644